# magento 2.2 adding a new theme installation

Tags: magento

I´m having problems understanding how to install a new theme in my magento 2.2 and i was hopping someone could help me understand what it is, what i did was:

I installed magento 2.2 from [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download). and then choose "Full release with sample data" community edition 2.2.0. The installation went well and i can access to my admin panel adn everything else.

Next i found [this](http://www.hiddentechies.com/bizkick-responsive-theme-magento-2.html#) template and downloaded the package **Bizkick v1.0.3**, unzipped it and then i have two directories, which are "app" and "pub". After this i dragged these to my magento root, overwrite the ones that were there and now, i CANNOT access anything, not my initial page nor my admin, i have tried with other themes and the same thing keeps happening. I also have disabled my cache in the admin like the instructions said and them perform the above but with no luck.

Can anyone enligh me? 
Regards.